# Swagger code generator adds JsonProperty on all generated class properties

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag

I have a problem regarding swagger code generator (NSwagStudio).

It generates CSharpClient where all classes have JsonProperty which sets NullValueHandling = Ignore

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("errors", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

How can I avoid this behaviour during code generation in swagger code generator (NSwagStudio).

Comment: https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/1129

Comment: Thank you very much it worked